# Regarding the archimedean property

Tags: calculus

Proposition:
**For every real number $E>0$ there is a natural number $M$ such that for all natural numbers $n>M$, $\frac{1}{n}<{E}$**

I am not sure how to prove this.

I think if M=E then ofcourse in fractions the larger the denominator the smaller it will become.

Unless n and m are both one. But n must greater than m.

Comment: You must think at "little" values of $E$, i.e. when $E < 1$. For $E > 1$, clearly it is enough to choose $M = 1$, and for all $n > M$ surely $1/n < E$.

Comment: Well when E is greater than 1 it will be true because n is natural number.

Comment: When $E < 1$ you must write it as $0.q_1 q_2 q_3 ... \times 10^{-k}$, with $q_1 \ne 0$. Then, for sure $1/10^k < E$. Thus, set $M = 10^k$.

Comment: What do you know is true? This is sometimes called the Archimedean property, or is immediately derived from the Archimedean property

Comment: The [archimedean principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Archimedean_Principle) implies that $\forall E>0\exists p\in \mathbb N(p>E)$ and this is equivalent to $\color{blue}{\forall F>0\exists p\in \mathbb N\left(F>\dfrac 1 p\right)}$.

So to prove your statement, take $E>0$. The blue formula guarantees the existence of $M\in \mathbb N$ such that $E>\dfrac 1M$. Since $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(n\ge M\implies \dfrac1M\ge \dfrac 1n\right)$ the result follows. I removed the tag (elementary-number-theory) from your post on purpose. This is calculus, it has nothing to do with number theory.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not know it is calculus.... I see the archimedean principles says that natural numbers are unbounded above but they are below as 1 is the smallest natural number

Comment: Natural numbers **are** bounded below (by $1$ or $0$ ...); but we exploit the fact that as $n > M$ "grows" then $1/n$ (which is $< 1$ when $n >1$) "diminish". The "idea" (as per my comments above) is that if $E \ge 1$, then $M=1$ is enough. When $0 < E < 1$, you can always find a *natural* number $M$ "big enough" such that $1/M \le E$; form that $M$ "onwards", all natural numbers $n > M$ will satisfy the inequality : $1/n < 1/M \le E$.